# UDP socket listener not receiving data

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, udp, udpclient

My local ip is : 192.168.0.70,
External ip is : 192.168.0.50 : 60000

I want receive data from external ip sending to local ip. I use Socket class because i can send data using remote IPEndPoint. But when Udp connection closed, local ip's port dynamically changing. How can i receive data?

```
private static void UdpConnect()
    {
        try
        {
            IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.50"), 60000);

            Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
            client.Connect(remoteEP);

            byte[] sendbuffer = { 1, 2, 3 };

            client.Send(sendbuffer);

            byte[] receivebuffer = new byte[512];

            client.Receive(receivebuffer);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a UDP connection, so it can not close.

Comment: You will likely need a statically assigned IP from your router and port forwarding set up. This is assuming you have a static external IP.

Comment: I don't quite follow why the local ip's port has to change ?

Comment: @PhilipStuyck we do not permission to do with router or port forwading. we must find another way.

Comment: @PhilipStuyck When computer shut down or udp connection closed, port is changing. If this happens our program not to be stable.

Comment: You bind to make it a fixed port.

Comment: Or you just don't close the socket. If you close and then send again a different ephemeral port will be allocated. Hence your moving port number.

Comment: also show the server code. This is only the client code.

Comment: My access controller's program is not  need fixed port also wireshark. i can solve this problem with programming.

Comment: I dont have server code. i connected RFID reader to my second network card. That is sending data.

Comment: i solved. The source of problem is access controller. İt accepted special byte array to connect.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to listen on a specific local port, use Socket.Bind and then Socket.ReceiveFrom.
You don't need the Socket.Connect call since UDP is a connectionless protocol.

Comment: İ can not use Socket.Bind beca its parameter is must be 'Local EndPoint' and i dont know local port number.
I tried  'EndPoint remoteEndPoint = remoteEP;
    client.ReceiveFrom(buffera, ref remoteEndPoint);'. not worked

Comment: The receiving end is the one who prescribes the port number, so you must decide on that and the sending end must use the same number. It's just like your browser (the sender) usually sends the HTTP requests to the server on a predefined port (80 by default). So when calling Bind you tell the system "Messages coming in on port N are for me" and then when you call the ReceiveFrom, you get the message. The second param (remoteEndPoint) is your way to know where the messages are coming from, since when using UDP you don't know that up front (that's because it's conectionless).